# Difference between CLR and CLI

Tags: .net, clr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CLR and CLI - What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480752/clr-and-cli-what-is-the-difference)

What is the difference between CLR and CLI? (in .NET)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [CLR and CLI - What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480752/clr-and-cli-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: You should probably just post this as a comment.