# Does Mono Implement CLR? Or At Least Some Unmanaged InternalCall? Or Nothing?

Tags: .net, performance, mono, ilspy

We know that C# uses unmanaged code like P/Invoke or CLR implemented code like InternalCall. What I want to know is does mono it self implements a complete CLR or just some unmanaged code or nothing?
  I can use .Net Reflactor or ILSpy to view managed assembly, but some times due to performance issues I need to know how does CLR implement some unmanaged code. Like: How does System.String.get_lenght() do?
  Any one can answer questions above or some infomation about this is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: It implements the CLR.  Looking at the code is not an issue, Mono is Open Source.

Comment: @Hans : I just got the mono code. Is it possible to ask which directory should I look into?

Comment: Yes, reflector works on mono assemblies, they are the same binary format ( which is the whole idea really ).

Comment: Mono's System.String is implemented here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs - the Length property is not an icall.

Comment: Is it more correct to say Mono implements the CLI, than it implements the CLR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, mono does implement the whole CLR, so if you looked at its code, you would find the implementation of methods like `String.get_Length()`.

But Mono is a different implementation than the Microsoft CLR. What that means is if you look up the code for `String.get_Length()` in Mono then the Microsoft CLR could have completely different way of doing the same thing.

Another option is looking at [Shared Source Common Language Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure). It's from Microsoft and it's probably more similar to their implementation of CLR than Mono, but it still isn't the same. And the newest available version corresponds to .Net 2.0.

Comment: I know that mono is not Microsoft. But a reference is way much better than nothing. I'm searching the mono code, still looking for it.

Comment: Will the upcoming .Net core 1.0 use Mono underneath for its CLR related job?

Comment: Nitpick: Should your second reference to `String.get_lenght()` actually be `String.get_Length()`?  If no, can you please explain why?

Comment: @kevinarpe Yeah, fixed. Thanks.